# RDLC Adding page break within a table

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc

Wondering if anyone who has extensive experience with RDLC can give me a clue how to set this up.

So currently I have a report setup as such:

> Header
>
> Table start
>
> Row `That repeats at the start of every page`
>
> ```
> Here I want to add the work Remark but I need it to just display once 
> and take full page but also have the above Row still repeat on every page
> but putting it as a header is not an option
> ```
>
> Group1 `Prints info based off of an account and repeats until it has gone through all accounts`
>
> Table end
>
> Footer

Between the table and the Row that repeats at the start of every page I want to add a page break. Everything I have tried has not worked right(resized the row to the size of the page, added a rectangle inside at the top of group 1 and set a page break and added the word Remark in another row above the rectangle... Remark shows after the page break)

Starting to run out of ideas for some that seems entirely too simple. My wording may be a little off please let me know if more clarification would help.

Essentially it should look like:

> Header Page1
>
> Report title and type
>
> Remarks:
>
> Footer Page1
>
> ---
>
> Header Page2
>
> Report title and type
>
> Item1
>
> Subitem1
>
> Item2
>
> Subitem2
>
> Footer Page2
>
> ---
>
> Header Page3
>
> Report title and type
>
> Item3
>
> Subitem3
>
> So on and so Forth
>
> Footer Page3

Comment: Before I can help you I you to clear a few things up first. I assume you want the same `Header` and `Footer` on every page? Do you wish to have the same `Report Title` on every page or does it depend on the group? The `Remarks` component is meant for only the first page?

Comment: Correct. Basically the Header and footer will always be the same. But the report title will vary but should be displayed on every page. The Remarks just needs to be on the First page after the report title.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would set up the report you described, and should deliver the wanted result.

> Header Page
>
> Report title 1 `This should be a TextBox which you fill by parameter, this is only for the first Title on the first page`
>
> Remarks: `Again use one or multiple TextBoxes filling it by parameter as it shouldn't be repeated.`
>
> > *Rectangle - start* `using a List element here on which you group. You could set the size of the rectangle so it takes the space of a single page, this way it will definitely break even if two items would fit on a single page. If the content exceeds the rectangle's size then it will simply grow and continue on the next page to break correctly again for the next element. But if you want multiple items on a page if possible, just make the rectangle wrap exactly around the content (and not stretch an entire page).  For both situation you need to make sure the` ***`Keep contents together on a single page, if possible`*** `and` ***`Add a page break after`*** `are checked, this will add a page-break after the Remarks.`
> >
> > > Report title # `This is a TextBox but not from a parameter but from the datasource(/set) based on the grouped element that you're displaying. If you want the title to be repeated when the item exceeds the page's size, just set the` ***`RepeatWith`*** `property to the element below it, being a Tablix for example.`
> > >
> > > Item # `This is any component, probably a Table (tablix) but this could also be another List (rectangle).`
> > >
> > > > SubItem # `Rows of the tablix for example, or this could nest even deeper ...`
> >
> > *Rectangle - end*
>
> Footer Page